# How do I copy test report from docker to Agent when my dotnet tests fail in Docker Build?

Tags: .net, docker, specflow, vstest, vsdoc

I am trying to run my Automation "Specflow+ Runner" C# Test Cases using docker.
I have a master.yml file which uses the Shared Agent and it builds docker image using Dockerfile.

master.yml

```
jobs:
  - job: run_docker_build
    displayName: Run UI Build
    steps:
#------------------------------------------
# Build Docker
#------------------------------------------
      - task: Docker@2
        displayName: DockerBuild
        env:
         COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD: 1
         DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1
        inputs:
         containerRegistry: "XXX"
         repository: run-automation-ui
         command: build
         Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
         tags: |
          latest
          $(Build.BuildId)

#------------------------------------------
# Copy the Results from Build Image
#------------------------------------------
      - pwsh: |
         $id=docker images --filter "label=Test=True" -q | Select-Object -First 1
         docker create --name testcontainer $id
         docker cp testcontainer:/src/AutomationTests/TestResults ./TestResults
         docker cp testcontainer:/src/AutomationTests/TestResults/Screenshots ./Screenshots
         docker rm testcontainer
        displayName: 'Copy Test Results'
        condition: always()
#------------------------------------------
# Publishing Test Results
#------------------------------------------
      - task: PublishTestResults@2
        inputs:
         testResultsFormat: 'VSTest'
         testResultsFiles: '**/*.trx'
         searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TestResults'
         publishRunAttachments: true
        displayName: 'Publish Test Results' 
        condition: always()
```

Docker File

```
LABEL Test=True
##Method one (#Even if test fails the build task will finish and in later stage I can copy the Results ) 
#RUN dotnet test -c Release --no-build --logger "trx;LogFileName=/src/AutomationTests/TestResults/test_results.trx" --filter TestCategory=DockerTest || true 

#Method Two (#Even if test fails the build task will finish and in later stage I can copy the Results )
#RUN dotnet test -c Release --no-build --logger "trx;LogFileName=/src/AutomationTests/TestResults/test_results.trx" --filter TestCategory=DockerTest; exit 0 

#Method Three (#Even if test fails the build task will finish and in later stage I can copy the Results )
#RUN dotnet test -c Release --no-build --logger "trx;LogFileName=/src/AutomationTests/TestResults/test_results.trx" --filter TestCategory=DockerTest; \
#echo $? > /dotnet.exitcode;
#RUN exit $(cat /dotnet.exitcode)

#Method Four (if test fails means still i need to able to copy the results )
#RUN dotnet test -c Release --no-build --logger "trx;LogFileName=/src/AutomationTests/TestResults/test_results.trx" --filter TestCategory=DockerTest
```

I am looking how can I copy my results if any Tests failed in Dockerfile means

Comment: Don't add your code as images

Comment: Modified my question as suggest removed image and used code block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than running `dotnet test` in a `RUN` instruction, you can define it as an `ENTRYPOINT` so that whenever you execute the container, it runs the tests. That integrates the exit code behavior directly with the running of the container.

This can be done with a multi-stage Dockerfile, dedicating a specific stage for testing purposes.

Here's an example Dockerfile taken from that demonstrates this pattern (taken from https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/e576a1e988bc9320ba971866b01404f4d040afb7/samples/complexapp/Dockerfile):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /source

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY complexapp/*.csproj complexapp/
COPY libfoo/*.csproj libfoo/
COPY libbar/*.csproj libbar/
RUN dotnet restore complexapp/complexapp.csproj

# copy and build app and libraries
COPY complexapp/ complexapp/
COPY libfoo/ libfoo/
COPY libbar/ libbar/
WORKDIR /source/complexapp
RUN dotnet build -c release --no-restore

# test stage -- exposes optional entrypoint
# target entrypoint with: docker build --target test
FROM build AS test
WORKDIR /source/tests

COPY tests/*.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore tests.csproj

COPY tests/ .
RUN dotnet build --no-restore

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test", "--logger:trx", "--no-restore", "--no-build"]

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c release --no-build -o /app

# final stage/image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "complexapp.dll"]
```

To use this test stage, you would first need to run `docker build`, targeting that specific stage:

```
docker build --target test -t tester .
```

When you run the container, you can volume mount a path from the host to the container so that you can have access to the test results. Here's an example using the paths you indicated in your question:

```
docker run --rm -v $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TestResults:/src/AutomationTests/TestResults tester
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your Answer. I tried exactly as you Mentioned with Multi Stages.I Kept 3 different Stages in my Dockerfile **restore**, **build** and **test**.
From my master.yml I am calling docker build --target restore -t tester . && docker build --target build -t tester . && docker build --target test -t tester . (I made 1 Test to fail)
Next I am calling docker run --rm -v $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TestResults:/src/AutomationTests/TestResults tester
When I added Task powershell task $fileExists = Test-Path -Path "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TestResults/*" (False)

Comment: Dockerfile
`code
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS base

WORKDIR /AutomationTests

COPY /AutomationTests /AutomationTests/AutomationTests/

WORKDIR /AutomationTests/AutomationTests

From base AS restore
RUN dotnet restore "AutomationTests.csproj" --configfile "nuget.config"   

FROM restore AS build
RUN dotnet build -c Release --no-restore

FROM build AS test
LABEL Test=True
RUN dotnet test -c Release --no-build --logger "trx;LogFileName=test_results.trx" --filter TestCategory=DockerTest

`

Comment: Master.yml **One**
`code
    steps:
      - script: |
            docker build -f **/Dockerfile --target restore -t XXX.azurecr.io/automation-ui:$(Build.BuildId) .
      - script: |
            docker build -f **/Dockerfile --target build -t XXX.azurecr.io/automation-ui:$(Build.BuildId) .
      - script: |
            docker build -f **/Dockerfile --target test -t XXX.azurecr.io/automation-ui:$(Build.BuildId) .
`

Comment: Master.yml **Two**
`code
      - script: |
            docker run --rm -v $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TestResults:/AutomationTests/AutomationTests/TestResults XXX.azurecr.io/automation-ui:$(Build.BuildId)
            docker run --rm -v $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Screenshots:/AutomationTests/AutomationTests/TestResults/Screenshots XXX.azurecr.io/automation-ui:$(Build.BuildId)


`

Comment: What I have noticed is as 1 of the Test is failing below steps are not happening
`code
#13 exporting to image
#13 sha256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
#13 exporting layers
#13 exporting layers 0.1s done
#13 writing image sha256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx done
#13 naming to docker.io/library/automation-ui-1749927 done
#13 DONE 0.1s
Finishing: test
`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Matt your solution worked perfectly. Initially I misunderstood you answer and did it in a wrong away. After going through your steps carefully I did it correctly. In process I have learnt a lot. Once again thanks a lot. -v (volume) worked perfectly.

Comment: Good to hear. Please mark this as an answer.